# ServiceStack.Redis Sentinel simple setup, "No Redis Sentinels were available"

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack.redis

There are other questions similar to this but I wanted to boil this down to the bare bones.

I am running a `.NET` application (`C#`) and am trying to connect to and monitor a group of `redis` servers running sentinel (3x sentinel monitoring 1 master and 2 slaves). They are on `linux` boxes.

I can use `ServiceStack.Redis` to write/read to the the master of the three if I hard-code that server. What I want to do is monitor sentinel to see which is master to make that read/write dynamic.

Here is my code:

```
var sentinelHosts = new[]{ "server01Name", "server02Name", "server03Name" };
var sentinel = new RedisSentinel(sentinelHosts, masterName: "mymaster");;

IRedisClientsManager redisManager = sentinel.Start();
```

This throws an exception which says `No Redis Sentinels were available`.

I'm sure I am missing something very simple but I can't seem to get traction on this.

I am running `redis` version 4.0.1 and `ServiceStack.Redis` version 4.5.14.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was very simple. The `masterName` MUST match the master name in your sentinel setup server side.